# validate and sort date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tablesorter

I am using the table sorter plugin to sort my tables.
I want to be able to catch date column in format:

**dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm**

and then sort them correctly (for this I have to switch days with years).

Here is what I've so far:

```
ts.addParser({
        id: "hebreLongDate",
        is: function (s) {
            return /\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{2,4} d{1,2}:d{1,2}/.test(s);
        }, format: function (s, table) {
            var c = table.config;
            s = s.replace(/\-/g, "/");
            // reformat the string in ISO format
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1");
            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s).getTime());
        }, type: "numeric"
    });
```

It does not work.

I would appreciate any help, especially if it comes with an explantation on the meaning of the correct regex.

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser doesn't really validate the date. The `is` function only detects if the format matches the pattern for the `format` function which is why it is just easier to make it return false and manually set the parser for a column using the `headers` option:

```
headers: {
    1: { sorter: "hebreLongDate" }
},
```

The `is` function above is requiring a `HH:mm` within the pattern, so if the first table cell in the column doesn't match, it ignores that parser. So either way it would be better to manually set the parser.

Anyway, here is how I would write the parser you are describing ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/1056/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "hebreLongDate",
    is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        s = s
            // replace separators
            .replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/[\-.,]/g, "/")
            // reformat dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd
            .replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\s](\d{1,2})[\/\s](\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1");

       return s ? $.tablesorter.formatFloat( (new Date(s).getTime() || ''), table) : s;
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

As for explaining the regex, there isn't that much of a difference between the code above and what you have in your question. The biggest difference is that the above code ensures that only one space exists between the date and time and that the date can be separated by a slash, dash, period, comma or space (i.e. `1-1-2000`, `1 1 2000` etc).

---

Update: if you want to have this parser be autodetected, then use the following `is` regex ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/1059/)). But it is important to note, that this regex cannot distinguish mmddyyyy from ddmmyyyy so it will always detect ddmmyyyy. To override this, set the header sorter option to "shortDate":

```
is: function(s) {
    // testing for ##-##-####, so it's not perfect; time is optional
    return (/(^\d{1,2}[\/\s]\d{1,2}[\/\s]\d{4})/).test((s || '').replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/[\-.,]/g, "/"));
},
```

Comment: I am calling the table sorter init once for all my pages, and in them there are many tables - so I would rather implement the logic in the is function to allow for empty strings or date in the correct format. Could you please help me with the regex for this function? thanks a lot :)